Issue in sending the reply mail In salesforce
I have an LWC Component which have two buttons one is for new mail and another one is for reply mail there is no issue in sending new mail, but for reply mail button when user click it, need to send  reply mail for last sended mail of lead record, I will refer many in internet but i will not get it, need your guidance in it
Thanks in advance !!
I will try to achive it by using singleEmailMessage Methods
